# Android Converting from NV21 Preview Format on Nexus one to JPEG

Tags: android, image, camera, jpeg

How can I convert from NV21 to JPEG. Currently, NV21 is the only `previewFormat` that is supported by the camera on a Nexus One (running Android 2.2).

Thanks.

Comment: I do the conversion from NV21 to JPEG in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535652/takepicture-hangs-on-android-2-3-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is class to work with YUV images - [YuvImage](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/YuvImage.html). And this class have method compressToJpeg.
But it only for android 2.2. In more popular 2.1 there is no such class.
So you need write code by yourself (for 2.1) to convert to rgb and than use Bitmap class.
But you lucky to have 2.2 (I'm stuck with official 2.1 on htc hero forever =((( )

Btw, thank to google for "powerful" API.

Answer (score 0):

`p.setPreviewFormat(PixelFormat.JPEG);` no?

where `p = Camera.getParameters();`

Comment: No this doesn't work because `p.getSupportedPreviewFormats()` only returns a list of size 1 and contains the value that maps to `ImageFormat.NV21`.

Comment: "It is strongly recommended that either NV21 or YV12 is used, since they are supported by all camera devices." (c) http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setPreviewFormat%28int%29