# takepicture hangs on Android 2.3.3

Tags: android, camera

I have some codes of taking picture which works in Android 2.1 and 2.2.
But these codes broke at Android 2.3.
After spending time to fix this issue which went in vain, I would like to ask for help here.

My code flow to take picture is like this:

**create a class Camlayer extends SurfaceView**

```
public class CamLayer extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private void init(Context context){
        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        mCamera = Camera.open();
    }

    public CamLayer(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public CamLayer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        Log.i(TAG+".surfaceChanged", "being called!");
        Log.i(TAG+".surfaceChanged", "w="+w); 
        Log.i(TAG+".surfaceChanged", "h="+h);
        if (isPreviewRunning) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        }

        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.setPreviewCallback(mPreviewCallback);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG+".surfaceCreated", "mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);");
        }

        Camera.Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();  
        setOptimalSize(p, w, h, SIZEOFPREVIEW);
        setOptimalSize(p, w, h, SIZEOFPICTURE);
        mCamera.setParameters(p);

        mCamera.startPreview();
        isPreviewRunning = true;
    }

    public void takePicture(){
        Log.i(TAG+".takePicture", "being called!");
        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPictureCallback);
        Log.i(TAG+".takePicture", "call ended!");
    }
}
```

`CamLayer.takePicture()` will be called by external classes to start.

The problem is that at Android 2.3.3, the `takePicture` will hang, so an ANR problem is found. In `/data/anr/traces.txt`, below are found. As you can see, the `native_takePicture` never returns.

DALVIK THREADS:

```
(mutexes: tll=0 tsl=0 tscl=0 ghl=0 hwl=0 hwll=0)
"main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE

  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40022170 self=0xce68

  | sysTid=2411 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=-1345006464

  at android.hardware.Camera.native_takePicture(Native Method)

  at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:746)

  at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:710)

  at oms.cj.tube.camera.CamLayer.takePicture(CamLayer.java:256)

  at oms.cj.tube.camera.DefineColor.takePicture(DefineColor.java:61)

  at oms.cj.tube.camera.DefineColor.onKeyUp(DefineColor.java:71)

  at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:1280)

  at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2078)

  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:16
66)
  at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverKeyEventToViewHierarchy(ViewRoot.java:2571)

  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleFinishedEvent(ViewRoot.java:2546)

  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1878)

  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)

  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)

  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)

  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)

  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Is there anybody having the same problem? And know how to fix it?

Comment: It would help if you included the segment of code that is the source of the error. You don't include your custom PictureCallback class or even create an instance of it. Where is mPictureCallback defined, and where is the source for its Class? On top of that, where is the rest of your CamLayer Class, the code as it's written now wouldn't even compile, let alone get as far as the error your experiencing.  I'd be more than happy to help but it's next to impossible without all the details.

Comment: On a HTC Sensation, my custom camera app, shows the preview on the full screen space. When user taps the screen, focus is called. When focus is complete and successful, I call mCamera.takePicture . Sometimes it works, and I get the callback for saving JPG data, other times it just stays in takePicture, without timeout nor any debug messages. This is so annoying , having to restart the phone every time, and not knowing what the problem is. SettingsPreviewCallback to null doesn't help. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 7):

I also observed mCamera.takePicture(null, null, handler) to freeze. I tried to clear the preview handler: mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null) before calling takePicture(), and it works now.

Answer (score 5):

I had the exact same problem today when testing our app on a Samsung Exhibit 4G with Android 2.3.3 and solved it using a workaround.

I don't call **takepicture** anymore but use the last preview callback as the picture.

The problem is that the preview callback sends the data buffer using the NV21 format.

So you have to convert the image using this process: NV21 -> RGB -> Load the Bitmap -> Compress to JPEG

Our code right now looks like this:

```
    camera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback() {

        @Override
        public synchronized void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera arg1) {
            if (!mTakePicture) {
                CameraPreview.this.invalidate();
            } else {

                if (mTakePictureCallback != null && !mPictureTaken) {
                    int rgb[] = new int[previewSize.width*previewSize.height];
                    decodeYUV420SP(rgb, data, previewSize.width, previewSize.height);
                    Bitmap memoryImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(rgb, previewSize.width, previewSize.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    memoryImage.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
                    shutterSound();
                    setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getContext().getResources(), memoryImage));
                    mTakePictureCallback.onPictureTaken(baos.toByteArray(), arg1);
                }
                mPictureTaken = true;
                camera.stopPreview();
            }
        }
    });
```

The code of **decodeYUV420SP** is here http://www.41post.com/3470/programming/android-retrieving-the-camera-preview-as-a-pixel-array who found it on Ketai http://code.google.com/p/ketai/

When you take a picture just set the **mTakePicture** variable on **true**

I'm working on a better version but this should get you going.

Comment: You could use the YuvImage class but it only works on API >= 8, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/YuvImage.html

Comment: This is ludicrous, Camera.takePicture works just fine and you get a full resolution JPEG when it returns.  Why on Earth would you want to go to such ridiculous lengths to generate your own ultra low resolution version?

Comment: this fix was only related to certain camera where takePicture just hangs. That was a problem we had testing our app with android on 10+ different devices/os versions. However as you state the images generated are lower resolution, anyhow that's better than no picture or app hanging

Comment: Right, so you tested your app on 10 different devices and none of them worked properly so obviously they were all defective, it couldn't possibly have been improperly written code.

Comment: No, one of the os/device versions (read the first paragraph:  Samsung Exhibit 4G with Android 2.3.3) had the problem. Btw we had 3 different cases in that time 1) some worked perfectly calling the system camera 2) some worked implementing our own camera 3) this os/device. We could have ignored it, we ended up doing it. Yet this was the only solution we found working for that specific case and that's why I posted it here.

Comment: not the best approach as we sometimes need the full resolution jpeg and not much to do with the preview data.

Comment: This approach is good for super burst mode on Camera (like 10 snaps in a second or even more images per sec)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the setOptimalSize method used in your code, but make sure you have set camera parameter

```
mCamera.setPictureSize(captureSize.width, captureSize.height);
mCamera.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lie in the fact that below codes are writen.

1. There is a PreviewCallback defined,

   ```
   PreviewCallback mPreviewCallback = new PreviewCallback() {

       @Override
           public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
               //Log.i(TAG+".mPreviewCallback.onPreviewFrame", "being called!");
           }
   };
   ```
2. mCamera.setPreviewCallback(mPreviewCallback);
3. mCamera.takePicture()

That works in 2.1/2.2, but not in 2.3.

Not sure if Android team supported this way of using camera. 
If the above flow is expected, then Android team should fix this problem.

Comment: So if you take this code out, does you camera activity works and do you get pictures taken?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue with GB phones, and for me, it turned out to be because I was calling camera.startPreview() right after calling camera.takePicture(), and this was causing some thread locking in Android. The fix was to move camera.startPreview() *into* the callback passed into camera.takePicture(), such that it only got called once the picture data was in (example code below). This is of course only relevant if you're interested in restarting the preview after the picture is taken.

```
// BAD BAD DON'T DO THIS!
public void myTakePicture(Camera.PictureCallback callback) {
  mCamera.takePicture(null, null, null, callback);
  mCamera.startPreview();
}

// ...
// The way that worked for me
public void myTakePicture(final Camera.PictureCallback callback) {
  mCamera.takePicture(null, null, null, new Camera.PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] pictureData, Camera camera) {
      callback.onPictureTaken(pictureData, camera);
      mCamera.takePicture();
    }
  });
}
```

This not only made the ANR go away when calling takePicture, but also fixed a native crash on startPreview that was happening on some higher end phones (particularly a >=4.3 Nexus 5). Hope it helps!